# Find basis for the Kernel (Nullspace) of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V = \mathbb{R}^{2x2}$ be the vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$,
> and $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$. Also let a
> linear tranformation $T: V \rightarrow V$, with $T(X) = X^t+AX, \quad
>  X \in V$. I am asked to find a basis for the kernel and for the image.

My try is:
Let $X = \begin{pmatrix} α & β \\γ & δ \end{pmatrix}$, then $X^t = \begin{pmatrix} α & γ \\β & δ \end{pmatrix} $, and $AX = \begin{pmatrix} α-γ & β-δ \\-γ & -δ \end{pmatrix}$ and thus $T(X) = \begin{pmatrix} 2α-γ & β-δ+γ \\β-γ & 0 \end{pmatrix} $

Now the kernel is: $\operatorname{Ker}(T) = \{ X \in V \mid T(X) = 0_V \}$. Again let a random $X$ array, then $T(X) = 0$
and thus I have: $2α = γ, β = γ, β -δ + γ = 0$, so putting all that in a matrix and row reducing it, I get: $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0  \\0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Let $δ = t$, we have that $α = \frac{t}{4}, β = \frac{t}{2}, γ = \frac{t}{2}$, so putting that in the starting matrix $X = t\begin{pmatrix}  \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & 1\end{pmatrix}$ so a basis for the kernel is: $\begin{pmatrix}  \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Am I correct here or am I missing something?

Comment: The two vectors in the kernel matrix are linearly dependent.

Comment: Are you sure there is a transpose in the formula for $T$? Because it doesn't make much sense. $X$ is a vector, not a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: @StefanOctavian Thanks for pointing it out, I wrote it wrong, my bad. The vector space is $V = \mathbb{R}^{2x2}$, NOT $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. And yes, it is the transpose that is used.